# How to match data in 6 specifc cells with a matrix and output value

Tags: vba, excel, matrix, lookup

as per usual, I will start with the fact that I am new to this and I hope I am not repeating any previous questions!

How to explain...I am trying to create a function that will check 6 specific cells in a row on Sheet A with a matrix array on Sheet B.

I.E: (Will use 3 cells for ease!)

Sheet A:

_______Col B | Col C | Col D

Row 2 _ |_     1 __ |**__** 0  **_ |__**       0

Sheet B:

_______Col B | Col C | Col D |   Matrix Number

Row 2  __     0  ____    0   __  __  0     __ __ _       1

Row 3  __     1  ____    1   __  __  0     __ __ _       2

Row 4  __     1  ____    0   __  __  0     __ __ _       3

So the result will be = 3

Then I can hopefully just repeat this formula in Sheet A for other combinations checking against the matrix in Sheet B.

Thanks again, really hope A) the question makes sense & B) its not a stupid question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've laid your your data on a single worksheet called Sheet B as follows.

[image]

The formula in E2 is,

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('Sheet B'!$E$6:$E$8, MAX(INDEX(ROW($1:$3)*('Sheet B'!$B$6:$B$8=B2)*('Sheet B'!$C$6:$C$8=C2)*('Sheet B'!$D$6:$D$8=D2),,))),"no match")
```

You should be able to move B1:E2 to Sheet A, add more rows to lookup and fill the formula down.

Comment: Cheers, thanks very much, had some trouble expanding it to 5 cells over 200 rows! Thanks again!